# RTSP live stream keep-alive

Tags: android, vlc, rtsp

I am trying to create android RTSP-client app which can view live RTSP streams. The problem is that the streams ends when the server timeout is reached. I checked with wireshark that client sends `RTSP OPTIONS` and server responds `RTSP OK`. Still after my set timeout (15 seconds) is reached the server stops sending video via UDP and the client tears the connection down. So it seems that the control connection is still alive, but the server stops streaming. I do not understand where client gets the BYE message. Any ideas what I could do here?

My test code is really basic and plain. 
Here is to most crucial part I think:

```
VideoView video1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("rtsp://myip:8552/t");
video1.setVideoURI(videoUri);

video1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
      mediaPlayer.start();
   }
});
```

And here is android studio log:

```
logcat:

04-21 15:13:35.993     115-7361/? I/ARTSPConnection﹕ status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-21 15:13:35.993     115-7361/? I/MyHandler﹕ OPTIONS completed with result 0 (Success)
04-21 15:13:37.483     115-7361/? I/MyHandler﹕ received BYE on track index 0
04-21 15:13:37.483     115-7361/? I/MyHandler﹕ received BYE on track index 1

04-21 15:13:49.523     115-7361/? I/ARTSPConnection﹕ status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-21 15:13:49.523     115-7361/? I/MyHandler﹕ OPTIONS completed with result 0 (Success)

04-21 15:13:52.513     115-7361/? I/MyHandler﹕ stream ended? aborting.
04-21 15:13:52.553     115-7361/? I/ARTSPConnection﹕ status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-21 15:13:52.553     115-7361/? I/MyHandler﹕ TEARDOWN completed with result 0 (Success)
```

And the the last communication between client and server:

```
OPTIONS rtsp://myip:8552/t RTSP/1.0
Session: be109033c48c17dc
User-Agent: stagefright/1.1 (Linux;Android 4.2.2)
CSeq: 6

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Server: VLC/2.2.0
Content-Length: 0
Cseq: 6
Public: DESCRIBE,SETUP,TEARDOWN,PLAY,PAUSE,GET_PARAMETER

TEARDOWN rtsp://myip:8552/t RTSP/1.0
Session: be109033c48c17dc
User-Agent: stagefright/1.1 (Linux;Android 4.2.2)
CSeq: 7

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Server: VLC/2.2.0
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 13:18:25 GMT
Session: be109033c48c17dc;timeout=15
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cseq: 7
```

Comment: I reckon something wrong going in RTCP, just check that your RTCP replies are fine.